# How do I pull the file locations (path and filename) for all files at a given FTP address?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, filesystems

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Background

I need to pull the file locations (path and filename) for all files at a given FTP address.

For files on a mapped network or local drive, this code would work:

```
foreach(string fileName f in Directory.GetFiles("C\\:SomeDirectory"), "*.*",
                                     SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    //do stuff with each file found
}
```

But this will NOT work over an FTP connection.  I have already found [this MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx) which covers the establishing of an FTPWebRequest, but it does not show me how to loop through each file found (in all nested directories as well).

I am using C# within a forms app.

## Question

How do I accomplish this:

```
foreach(string fileName f in Directory.GetFiles("C\\:SomeDirectory"), "*.*",
                                         SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        //do stuff with each file found
    }
```

With an FTP connection?

Many thanks!!

## UPDATE / Final Answer

Special thanks to @sunk for getting this going.  I made a minor tweek to his code that makes it fully recursive so that it can drill into nested folders.  Here is the final code:

```
       //A list that holds all file locations in all folders of a given FTP address:
        List<string> fnl= new List<string>(); 

        //A string to hold the base FTP address:
        string ftpBase = "ftp://[SOME FTP ADDRESS]";

        //A button-click event.  Can be a stand alone method as well
        private void GetFileLocations(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the file names from the FTP location:
            DownloadFileNames(ftpBase);

            //Once 'DownloadFileNames' has run, we have populated 'fnl'
            foreach(var f in fnl)
            {
                //do stuff
            }        
        }

        //Gets all files in a given FTP address.  RECURSIVE METHOD:
        public void DownloadFileNames(string ftpAddress)
        {
            string uri = ftpAddress;
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("pella", "PellaWA01!");
            reqFTP.EnableSsl = false;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                files.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            reader.Close();
            responseStream.Dispose();

            //Loop through the resulting file names.
            foreach (var fileName in files)
            {
                var parentDirectory = "";

                //If the filename has an extension, then it actually is 
                //a file and should be added to 'fnl'.            
                if (fileName.IndexOf(".") > 0)
                {
                    fnl.Add(ftpAddress.Replace("ftp://pella.upload.akamai.com/140607/pella/",              "http://media.pella.com/") + fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                //If the filename has no extension, then it is just a folder. 
                //Run this method again as a recursion of the original:
                    parentDirectory += fileName + "/";
                    try
                    {
                        DownloadFileNames(ftpAddress + parentDirectory);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at FtpWebRequest - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

Comment: it seems to me that the example you linked gives you everything you need. What's missing?

Comment: @vlad The OP wants to know how, exactly, to iterate over the files/directories returned (and do stuff with them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to get the files name local on your machine using FTPWebRequest.

```
WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
```

then use foreach {};

Here is the code:-

```
public List<string> DownloadFileNames()
        {
                string uri = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/";
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
                reqFTP.EnableSsl = true;
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = Settings.UsePassive;
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                List<string> files = new List<string>();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    files.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                reader.Close();
                responseStream.Dispose();
                return files;
        }
```

Now you have the List:-

```
List<string> FileNameList = DownloadFileNames();
foreach (var fileName in FileNameList)
{

}
```

Comment: You should look at the `using` keyword

Comment: Thanks sunk.  This looks promising.  One problem however--I have many nested folders.  Is there a command that will allow me to return the files within all nested folders as well or will I need to just write some code for that?  Thanks!

Comment: One suggestion. Just write a overload method **public List<string> DownloadFiles(string FileName)**. Call it again from your foreach loop, and concatenate the parameter **Filename** in **uri**. Like **string uri = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + FileName + "/"**;

Answer (score 1):

the ListDirectoryDetails command used in the example just returns a string.  You will have to manually parse it to build a list of files and subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ncl/thread/079fb811-3c55-4959-85c4-677e4b20bea3

```
    string[] files = GetFileList();
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Download(file);
    }

    public string[] GetFileList()
    {
        string[] downloadFiles;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        WebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/"));
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                result.Append(line);
                result.Append("\n");
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            // to remove the trailing '\n'
            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
            return result.ToString().Split('\n');
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }                
            downloadFiles = null;
            return downloadFiles;
        }
    }

    private void Download(string file)
    {                       
        try
        {                
            string uri = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + remoteDir + "/" + file;
            Uri serverUri = new Uri(uri);
            if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
            {
                return;
            }       
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;                
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + remoteDir + "/" + file));                                
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);                
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;                
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;                                
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;                 
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localDestnDir + "\" + file, FileMode.Create);                
            int Length = 2048;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
            int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);               
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            }                
            writeStream.Close();
            response.Close(); 
        }
        catch (WebException wEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(wEx.Message, "Download Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error");
        }
    }
```